# Logical file 'Test' is not part of database 'Test'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

When i use SMO code for database restore, it throws me below exception

**Exception detail**:

> Restore failed for Server 'servername'.     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
>   at DBBackupService.DBBackupService.RestoreDB() in line 115 : Inner
>   Stack Trace:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An
>   exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Logical file 'Test' is not part of database 'Test'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical
>   file names. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction
>   action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean
>   catchException)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   queries)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server
>   server, StringCollection queries)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)

Comment: Obviously, you are executing a restore statement that references a file named "Test" but the database you had backed up does not contain such a file.

Comment: It's quite obvious and exactly what the exception says: You are trying to recover the DB File "Test" from a Backup which does not include the corresponding file. So if you execute the suggested `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM ...` you will see the name of the DB file within your backup

Comment: Include the problem code in your question.

Comment: how do i use RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM

Comment: >>>how do i use RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM<<< RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk='Here is your bak file with full path to it'